# Redmine imap issue

Tags: email

I'm having a big problem with redmine. I want people to send a mail to :
it@myfirm.com and then redmine has to create a ticket.

So first I tried doing it with rake but I quickly realized that its just too much for people to enter the project name and tracker in the subject so now I want to solve it via CURL/post.

curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"issue":{"project_id": 8,"tracker_id": 3,"assigned_to_id":8,"priority_id":2,"subject":"Example","description":"testt"}}' http://project.com/projects/edv/issues.json?key=XXXXXXXXXX

It works but I Need to implement hooks in my imap (dovecot) so it checks if theres a new mail in the IT SPECIFIC mail dir and then creates a ticket.

cheers

Comment: That's not something you can do on the IMAP/dovecot side. You have to configure redmine to get the mails in some way (no idea what it offers for this) and act upon it.

Answer (score 0):

Redmine offers you a solution which should work for your need: http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineReceivingEmails

Comment: y i tried that but I need to configure redmine somhow to receive mails like SvW said, thats where im stuck

Comment: well, the page offers you two solution.

1. forward the mails to your redmine server and use the script `rdm-mailhandler.rb`, which imports the mails to redmine via http 

2. download them via imap. theres a `rake` command from the wikipost or use imapsync, getmail or something you are familiar with.